# Showing a JPopupmenu then selecting a JButton requires 2 clicks

Tags: java, swing, listener, jpopupmenu

It seems after showing a `JPopupmenu` using the `show()` method it requires 2 clicks to select a `JButton` or any component with a `ActionListener` attached to it; one click for the popup menu to disappear and another to be actually detected by the components with `ActionListener`.

Is there anyway to make it so it clicking on a button the first time is detected?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: It works fine for me. What `show()` method do you reffer to. Component's show() is deprecated.

Comment: @DSquare talking about the show(component, x, y) method in JPopupmenu. When I click on a JButton the popup disappears but the button is not selected.

Comment: With a comboBox and the showPopup() method it works fine. See Andrew Thompson comment, try making a very small program with the kind of popup you are using and a button where this happens. You might find an error elsewhere doing this.

Comment: Alright, i'll do that as soon as possible, thanks.